# Python fnmatch filter for patterns that include subdirectory

Tags: python, path

I'm trying to use fnmatch filter to find files given a pattern. However, if my pattern is something like `subdir/t*.txt` my code

```
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for fn in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
        print 'found match'
```

will never reach the print statement. From what I can see, it'll never find a match because files is only the basename, and will not include subdirectories. Is there a good way to match patterns that include a subdirectory? It should still work for patterns like `*.txt` though.

The only solution I have been able to come up with are clunky, with lots of `if` statements and extra `for` loops (i.e., checking if the pattern is a path, then creating all the possible paths from subdirectories then checking with `fnmatch`). Wondering if there is an elegant solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible by making `fnmatch.filter()` compare the full path of each file to when it contains subdirectories if you include a leading wildcard character to the pattern as show. Since doing this requires significantly more processing, it's probably worth checking whether it's necessary as shown.

```
root = ...
pattern = '*/subdir/subdir2/t*.txt'  # note leading wildcard character

if not os.path.dirname(pattern):  # no subdirectories in pattern
    # no need to compare full paths
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for fn in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
            print('found match - path: "{}", fn: "{}"'.format(path, fn))
else:
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
        # must compare full file paths to pattern when it contains directories
        filepaths = (os.path.join(path, file) for file in files)  # generator
        for fp in fnmatch.filter(filepaths, pattern):
            fn = os.path.basename(fp)
            print('match found - path: "{}", fn: "{}"'.format(path, fn))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer -- I used it and came up with something for what I needed.

Comment: The modified version will work with more than one subdirectory if you provide a leading wildcard character(s) to match a leading directory path, such as `*/subdir/subdir2/t*.txt`, in the `pattern`.

Answer (score 0):

I realized martineau's answer was still not quite what I needed because while it works great when I have a pattern like `subdir/pattern`, when I have something like `subdir/subdir2/pattern`, it doesn't quite work because `subdir = os.path.split(path)[1]` will get the individual subdir (in this case `subdir2`), but `subdir_pat` is `subdir/subdir2`, so it won't find any matches.

What I ended up doing was change this line

```
subdir = os.path.split(path)[1]  # isolate subdirectory name
```

to the following:

```
subdir = os.path.replace(root, '')  # I'm not too sure what is a better way to replace paths..
```

since I figured that when I check for subdirectories, it will be under root.

Any further feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Adding an "answer" like this really isn't the right way to ask follow-on questions. In this case, you should probably post a new question.